# Updatelocations method is executed twice causing results to duplicate

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

I'm trying to get the user's current location using a delegate and use them in another class to make an API call. Each time I send the locations it triggers the API call. The problem is that the delegate in the `didUpdateLocations` method is executed twice for the same location and then the API returns the same results twice and I only need it to make a call once and then again if the location change drastically.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    CLLocation * newlocation = [locations lastObject];
    if (newlocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
        return;
    }
    NSTimeInterval cachedTime = [newlocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (fabs(cachedTime) < 120) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (_delegate) {
            [self.delegate sendUserLocationWith: newlocation.coordinate.latitude andLongitude: newlocation.coordinate.longitude];
        }
    }
```

I have tried to use locations time stamp to prevent it but if I run my app twice under two minutes the delegate won't send the locations the second time would like it to send the user location once when I first load the app and again if it changes by more then 5m.

Answer (score 0):

keep last location and compare new reported location to the last when your delegate   is  called.

e.g.

```
if (fabs(cachedTime) < 120 || CLLocationEqualTo(lastLocation.coordinate,  newLocation.coordinate)) {
  return
}

lastLocation = newLocation;
if (_delegate) {
  [self.delegate sendUserLocationWith: newlocation.coordinate.latitude andLongitude: newlocation.coordinate.longitude];
}
```

Comment: Hi Daij-Djan thanks for your response. i tried this but the updateLocations method still runs at least twice and the delegate still sends the locations twice